# jQuery animate images: Fake slow image loading like with bad internet connection

Tags: jquery, animation

For the upcoming #InternetSlowdown protest I want to animate images so they look like they're loaded via a slow internet connection.

I want to animate that in jQuery.

```
$("img").hide().animate({height: ["toggle", "swing"]}, 3000);
```

The "toggle" effect is correct because it deshrinks the height.
But it should use the original height before and load the image from top to bottom into that "frame".

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/qs16g18n/

Comment: I have got an idea, why u don't overlay your original picture with white sheet the goes down with time.
Or include your img in div and set overflow to hidden and increase the height of div gradually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that, just give it a container with `overflow:hidden`.

```
<div class="SlowImgFrame">
    <img class="SlowImg" src="SlowImg.png" />
</div>
```

Set your CSS:

```
.SlowImg {
    height:100px;
}

.SlowImgFrame {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then animate the frame instead:

```
$('.SlowImgFrame').animate({
    height:100
},3000);
```

You can add whatever shmancy components to the animation you want, but that should give you the effect you want.